# Calling array of functions

Tags: python, numpy

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222318/python-add-function-to-an-array-in-a-for-loop) an array of functions is generated. Is there some vectorized way (ie. not an explicit loop) of calling them?

Example:

```
funcs = np.array(lambda x: 2*x, lambda x: 2.5*x)#in principle more funcs
args = np.array([3.0,4.0])

# numpy array of func[0](arg[0]), func[1](arg[1])
#output : array([6.0,10.0])
```

The functions are assumed to have the same signature, but are assumed to be non-trivial (eg. spline functions of a set of curves), and completely independent of eachother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.imap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap) as follows:

```
from itertools import imap
import numpy as np

funcs = np.array([lambda x: 2*x, lambda x: 2.5*x])
args = np.array([3.0,4.0])
answer = np.fromiter(imap(lambda func, arg: func(arg), funcs, args),float)
print(answer)
```

**Output**

```
[6.0, 10.0]
```

Comment: I accepted your answer, but changed from converting the iterable to numpy array instead of `list`.

Answer (score 1):

without import anything, try this:

```
import numpy as np
funcs = np.array(lambda x: 2*x, lambda x: 2.5*x)#in principle more funcs
args = np.array([3.0,4.0])

output = map(lambda x,y:x(y), funcs, args)
```

it works also on `list` and `tuple`.